# NotifyIcon cria vários ícones que não desaparecem com o encerramento programa

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

Tenho um Formulário Windows em que uso o componente NotifyIcon.

Ao executar o software o software pelo visual Studio e finalizar a execução com o botão de parar depuração:

[image: botão de parar depuração]

o ícone não é retirado ate que eu passe o mouse sobre ele:

[image: Múltiplos ícones de instâncias finalizadas do programa]

Já tentei seguir as instruções de algumas perguntas do stackoverflow mas nenhuma me ajudou. Deixarei o titulo com os links delas:

[NotifyIcon remains in Tray even after application closing but disappears on Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723843/notifyicon-remains-in-tray-even-after-application-closing-but-disappears-on-mous/21735901)

[Issue with NotifyIcon not disappearing on Winforms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067844/issue-with-notifyicon-not-disappearing-on-winforms-app)

---

**Como pedido o código referente a questão:**

Trecho de código responsável o controle do compotamento do NotifyIcon :

```
private bool allowVisible;     // ContextMenu's Show command used
private bool allowClose;       // ContextMenu's Exit command used

protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    if (!allowVisible)
    {
        value = false;
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated) CreateHandle();
    }

    UpdateBase(value);
}

private void UpdateBase(bool value)
{
    if (base.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new Action<bool>(UpdateBase);
        base.Invoke(d, new object[] { value });
    }
    else
    {
        base.SetVisibleCore(value);
    }
}

protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!allowClose)
    {
        this.Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}

private void showToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allowVisible = true;
    Show();
}

private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allowClose = true;
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Outras coisas associadas:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //Outras coisas sendo finalizadas
    notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
    notifyIcon1.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Não manjo de C#, mas em regra geral você tem de liberar ele antes de encerrar o aplicativo. Se o aplicativo estiver quebrando o ícone vai ficar mesmo, independente da língua de desenvolvimento. Sugiro que coloque uma rotina para encerrar o componente do ícone junto à rotina de finalização do aplicativo ou do formulário.

Comment: Já tentei algo assim, mas por algum motivo ele não passava pela rotina de encerramento do componente quando o programa encerrava. Teitei usar um método despose e um destrutor ao estilo c++. Tentarei novamente essa abordagem pois ela pode ter falhado por algum erro de implantação.

Comment: Mostre o código

Comment: Postarei ainda hoje. Tenho que selecionar os trechos adequados por ser software proprietário.

Comment: Add @LeandroAngelo

Comment: Esse comportamento acontece só quando está debugando o código? Se for isso acho que nem precisa se preoucupar

Comment: Caso eu encerre a aplicação através do gerenciador de tarefas também. Mas sim é somente nesses casos.